# Exit statuses of comparisons in test constructs

Tags: test, control-flow

I was writing some "if then" statements and found what seemed to me an odd behavior. Upon investigation I realized that it boiled down to the exit code of the comparison I was making. I illustrate my findings in the following code snippet.

As you can see

```
rc=1
[ $rc -eq 0 ]
es_num=$?
[ $rc=0 ]
es_str=$?
echo "es_num is $es_num"
echo "es_str is $es_str"
```

Outputs

```
es_num is 1
es_str is 0
```

Is there any documentation, preferably from the POSIX standards, that talks about the difference in the exit statuses of `-eq` and `=` in a test construct?

What should I be aware of when writing conditional statements? What are some best practices regarding this?

Portable code is preferable to Bash code (which I'm using).

Comment: I didn't know about the space being necessary. What I meant with "odd" is "weird if you read as pseudo code, ignoring the quirks of the language". Thanks. @ilkkachu

Comment: The only way I can get `[ $rc=0 ]` to fail with `rc=1` is to set `IFS` to 1 as well. That would cause both tests to error out and set `$?` to 2 (in `bash`).

Comment: @ilkkachu There was a typo. Of course I can't ignore them, but if I knew them, I wouldn't have to ask. That's exactly the point of the question.

Comment: @Elegance, ok, good, thanks. And yes, you're right, you wouldn't have to ask if you knew. It's just that even a typo like that can send the readers off in the wrong direction, looking for some really weird edge case that could explain the result. (The shell can be a bit quirky sometimes so there might have been a remote possibility of an edge case where both would return `1`...)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for the helpful feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-eq`

> True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal; otherwise, false.

[test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128)

`=`

> True if the strings s1 and s2 are identical; otherwise, false.

[test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128)

So `-eq` compares integers and `=` compares strings (which will also work with some limited integer cases).

---

You do have a syntax issue though, it should be:

```
[ "$rc" = 0 ]
```

And not

```
[ $rc=0 ]
```

`[ "$rc" = 0 ]`  **should** exit with 1 because `rc` does not equal 0

`[ $rc=0 ]` should actually exit with 0 because it's likely going to be treated as a string and the presence of a string within the `[` test construct will evaluate to true

---

With the sh `[` test there are a few differences:

```
# leading 0
$ [ 01 -eq 1 ]; echo $?
0
# adjacent whitespace
$ [ ' 1' -eq 1 ]; echo $?
0
# negative 0 vs positive 0
$ [ 0 -eq -0 ]; echo $?
0
```

However with the bash `[[` test there are a large number of differences (Including the ones mentioned above):

```
# base 8
$ [[ 032 -eq 26 ]]; echo $?
0
# Arithmetic expressions
$ [[ 1*6+32/15*2-1 -eq 9 ]]; echo $?
0
# Base 64
$ [[ 64#Hello_world -eq -5506400892957379251 ]]; echo $?
0
```

Comment: I'm just a bit confused about what is meant by numeric and string comparisons. Let's say I use `=` to compare numbers. When is it not going to not yield the same result as a numeric comparison?

Comment: Any examples with strings that have nothing but digits, and don't have leading zeros?

Comment: @Elegance The point is that with `-eq`, the left and right hand side are compared as integers, not as strings. The test would _evaluate_ the strings as integers (probably by passing them through `strtol()` or some such C function) before carrying out the comparison.

Comment: @Elegance In a `bash` test with `[[ ... -eq ... ]]` you could even have arithmetic calculations on either side, as in `[[ 1+1 -eq 2 ]]`. Obviously, `[[ 1+1 == 2 ]]` would not be true.

Comment: @Jesse_b You shared the same link twice. I take it the first one is incorrect.

Comment: @Elegance: Both operators are found in the same chapter of the document.

Answer (score 0):

For numeric comparisons you have to use `-eq` whereas `=` is for string comparisons (as from your variable naming you already seem to know).

One of the best introductions on the `test` aka `[` command I know is [The Unix Shell's Humble If](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-unix-shells-humble-if)